# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict' after I tried to add a Hstorefield to my model

Tags: migrate, hstore, django-hstore

I am developing an app in Django.

I tried to add a `Hstorefield` to my model, then I deleted it, and now I cannot anymore run the command `manage.py makemigrations` because I always get this error

```
(met5) C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest framework\Udemy Django\Metaglossario_Gestisco>python manage.py migrate Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, app_metaglossario, auth, contenttypes, sessions Running migrations:   Applying app_metaglossario.0045_model_node_data...Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 447, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

(met5) C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest framework\Udemy Django\Metaglossario_Gestisco>python manage.py makemigrations Migrations for 'app_metaglossario':   app_metaglossario\migrations\0054_model_node.py
    - Create model model_node

(met5) C:\Users\Tommaso\Django rest framework\Udemy Django\Metaglossario_Gestisco>python manage.py migrate Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, app_metaglossario, auth, contenttypes, sessions Running migrations:   Applying app_metaglossario.0045_model_node_data...Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 447, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Applicazioni_Tommaso\Phyton\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

It looks like that Hstorefiels is still having some effects on my database.

I tried to empty the model in which I pu the Hstorefield, then delete it, but nothing.
I even reset my database from Heroku, but the error keeps popping up.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: The only way I found to solve the problem was to manually delete the entire project and to git clone my backup in the same repository than before.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) for 2.0 or above, it is clearly stated that You need to **Setup the hstore extension in PostgreSQL**. I was also getting the same error, to solve this try this:

```
sudo su - postgres              //switch to postgres user
\c database;                     //connect your database
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;      //create extension
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to get it working

1. In your settings add the django.contrib.postgres as part of the installed apps.
2. create a migration before the migration that used the hstore field and Copy and paste the code below in the migration file.

   ```
   from django.db import models, migrations
   from django.contrib.postgres.operations import HStoreExtension, UnaccentExtension

   class Migration(migrations.Migration):

       dependencies = [
           ('main', '0001_initial'),
       ]

       operations = [
           HStoreExtension(),
           UnaccentExtension()
       ]
   ```
3. Create the migration that adds the hstore fields.
4. Run migration.

This worked for me!