# When i try to iterate over a RawQuerySet object in django i get "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

for example lets say

```
books.objects.raw(....)
```

the (...) are a representation of the sql parameters for example as seen in the django docs
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#:~:text=Django%20gives%20you%20two%20ways,ORM%20before%20using%20raw%20SQL!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#:%7E:text=Django%20gives%20you%20two%20ways,ORM%20before%20using%20raw%20SQL!)

when i try to iterate through the above oject like so

```
[print(x) for x in books.ojects.raw(...)]
```

I get this from my logs below

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170562/13964753

Comment: @Guillaume thanks well figured it out though...the issue was as i'm in postresql,the manner in which it handles dict is different from the way python/django traditionally does it